# MySQL multiple statement execution order

Tags: mysql, sql, routines

I have created a routine which inserts a record in one table, and after that it searches for that id (with a select statement) and updates another table's field with that id.Is this possible? It's one routine so my question is if the statements are executed in a sequential order?

Thanks in advance

Comment: as you have already written that routine you should try and execute it you will know. is there any error ? it will be executed in sequence.

Comment: cant you use an update trigger instead??

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need to search for the id. You can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the id of the last inserted row.

   `INSERT INTO tablename
   (<columns>)
   VALUES
   (<columnvalues>);`

   `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO somevariable;`
2. Then you can write your `UPDATE` statement.

   `UPDATE sometable
   SET sometable.col = somevariable
   WHERE sometable.something = @something`
3. Statements in a routine are executed in the order they are written.